# What is the difference between 'classifer.add' and 'keras.layers'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I am following a simple set of tutorials making convolutional neural networks in keras. I had two similar tutorials and wanted to make the code of the second a bit neater, so replaced the model creation style of the first tutorial with that of the second. It then gave me syntax errors. Is there a functional difference between adding a new layer in either of these styles? Do they have different use cases?

Code A

```
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu),
])
```

Code B

```
classifier = Sequential()

classifier.add(Dense(units = 128, activation = 'relu'))
```

Comment: There are no functional differences, but neither of those code samples produces a syntax error, so probably your problem is somewhere.

Comment: How did you import Sequential and Dense in Code B?